# HttpWatch: What is the meaning of Result ERROR 0x8?

Tags: httpwatch

Our users access many applications with Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7.  Intermittently they get "Page not found", only to retry the same operation a little later and get the correct result.  The requests to our internal systems do not go via a proxy.

We have used HttpWatch to capture an example of the problem, and at the time of the error we see an HTTP GET (on an HTTPS connection) fail with an HttpWatch Result of "ERROR 0x8".  The timeline graph shows 47ms of time to complete the request and all time of this time shows as Blocked.  No packets flow - the Downloaded Data bytes value is zero, as is the Uploaded Data bytes value.

I can find no details of the meaning of ERROR 0x8.  Do you know what this result means?

Thanks and regards...Paul

Answer (score 1):

Error 0x8 is from Windows:

ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY Not enough storage is available to process this command.

It's not clear why you are seeing this error. Please get in touch with HttpWatch Support (support@neumetrix.com) if you would like more assistance.